# Dynamic image change on keypress VB6

Tags: image, vb6, keypress

So I'm trying to make this form in VB6 with just an image, and whenever you press say the "Q" key that image changes, and if you press "E" it changes to back to the previous one. Simple stuff.

Here's what I have:

```
Private Sub Form_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
If KeyAscii = 81 Then Image.Picture = LoadPicture("E:\Imagenes\Avatars\4.jpg")
If KeyAscii = 69 Then Image.Picture = LoadPicture("E:\Imagenes\Avatars\3.gif")
End Sub
```

Well, that doesn't work. What could I do to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the Forms KeyPreview Property set to True?

Comment: Yes, I set it in Form_Load. Still, I get nothing. I'm thinking its a problem with loading the images, when I tried doing it in a command button it didn't work either. It says "The object doesn't allow this property or method."

Comment: You adding it directly to the Form or to a PictureBox

Comment: To an "Image" control. The default one, not PictureBox

Comment: Ok let me see if I can duplicate it, I am installing VB6 on my laptop now, needed to do it anyway.

Comment: Try Changing Image to Image1 or what ever the name of your Image control is. If it works I will post as an answer

Answer (score 0):

In reading your comment, you say that you are using the Default Image Control, there is not a Default Image Control you need to add an instance of it to your Form or just use the Forms Picture Property.

These examples work for me:

```
Private Sub Form_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If (Chr(KeyAscii) = "Q" Or Chr(KeyAscii) = "q") Then Form1.Picture = LoadPicture("E:\Imagenes\Avatars\4.jpg")
    If (Chr(KeyAscii) = "E" Or Chr(KeyAscii) = "e") Then Form1.Picture = LoadPicture("E:\Imagenes\Avatars\3.gif")
End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub Form_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If (Chr(KeyAscii) = "Q" Or Chr(KeyAscii) = "q") Then Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("E:\Imagenes\Avatars\4.jpg")
    If (Chr(KeyAscii) = "E" Or Chr(KeyAscii) = "e") Then Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("E:\Imagenes\Avatars\3.gif")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark, you were very helpful.

Indeed the main problem was that the name of the object was just "Image"... I don't know how that's relevant, but after I changed the name it worked fine with the code I was using before (btw, that Chr() function is really cool, I didn't know it :3).